# TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object python3

Tags: python

I have  updated my project to Python 3.7 and Django 3.0

Here is code of models.py

```
def get_fields(self):
        
        fields = []
        
        html_text = self.html_file.read()
        self.html_file.seek(0)
        
        # for now just find singleline, multiline, img editable
        # may put repeater in there later (!!)
        for m in re.findall("(<(singleline|multiline|img editable)[^>]*>)", html_text):
            # m is ('<img editable="true" label="Image" class="w300" width="300" border="0">', 'img editable')
            # or similar
            # first is full tag, second is tag type
            # append as a list
            # MUST also save value in here
            data = {'tag':m[0], 'type':m[1], 'label':'', 'value':None}
            title_list = re.findall("label\s*=\s*\"([^\"]*)", m[0])
            if(len(title_list) == 1):
                data['label'] = title_list[0]
            # store the data
            fields.append(data)
        
        return fields
```

Here is my error traceback

```
 File "/home/harika/krishna test/dev-1.8/mcam/server/mcam/emails/models.py", line 91, in get_fields
    for m in re.findall("(<(singleline|multiline|img editable)[^>]*>)", html_text):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 225, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

How can I solve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that python3's `read` returns bytes (i.e. "raw" representation) and not `string`. You can convert between bytes and string if you specify encoding, i.e. how are characters converted to bytes:

```
>>> '☺'.encode('utf8')
b'\xe2\x98\xba'

>>> '☺'.encode('utf16')
b'\xff\xfe:&'
```

the `b` before string signifies that the value is not `string` but rather `bytes`. You can also supply raw bytes if you use that prefix:

```
>>> bytes_x = b'x'
>>> string_x = 'x'
>>> bytes_x == string_x
False
>>> bytes_x.decode('ascii') == string_x
True
>>> bytes_x == string_x.encode('ascii')
True
```

Note you can only use basic (ASCII) characters if you are using `b` prefix:

```
>>> b'☺'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: bytes can only contain ASCII literal characters.
```

So to fix your problem you need to either convert the input to a string with appropriate encoding:

```
html_text = self.html_file.read().decode('utf-8')  # or 'ascii' or something else
```

Or -- probably better option -- is to use `bytes` in the `findall`s instead of strings:

```
        for m in re.findall(b"(<(singleline|multiline|img editable)[^>]*>)", html_text):
...
            title_list = re.findall(b"label\s*=\s*\"([^\"]*)", m[0])
```

(note the `b` in front of each "string")